# Generating dynamic charts with VBA

Tags: vba, dynamic, charts

I have to create almost 200 charts of time series. So I tried to write a macro that finishes most of the work I need to do.
I generated names for the time series like this as an example:

```
Name:= AKB_ExampleA
```

The name refers to a dynamic range which I declared with this formula:

```
=OFFSET('sheet1'!$C$7:$C$137;0;0;COUNT('sheet1'!$C$7:$C$206))
```

So now to the macro I coded so far:

```
Sub graphik_erstellen()

Call graphik1("AKB")

End Sub

Sub graphik(Name As String)
'
    Dim Ch As Chart
    Dim RngToCover As Range
    Set Ch = charts.Add
    Set Ch = Ch.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Charts")

    With Ch
      .ChartType = xlLine
      .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Name & "_ExampleA")
      .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("Datum_Volumen")
      .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "SERIES1"
      .FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
        With Selection.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
      .HasTitle = True
      .ChartTitle.Text = Name & ", Volumen (nach Korrektur)"
      .HasLegend = True
      .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
      .Legend.Select
        Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 11
        Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
      With .Parent
        .top = 100
        .left = 100
        .height = 287.149606299
        .width = 543.685039370078
        .Name = Name & "_chart"
      End With
End With

End Sub
```

My problem is, that if I do that, the dynamic range is not really considered. It takes the range of the name (which is $C$7:$C$137) but it should refer to the name itself (in order to be dynamic).
So if I click on the chart to see the series, the series values are declared as: `='sheet1'!$C$7:$C$137` instead of `='sheet1'!ExampleA`.

I would be really, really grateful if somebody could help me out.
Best
Elio

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. You should really set your `Range` using `Range`. Just to confirm what's the range on the sheet you looking st capturing into the chart?

Comment: Added paragraphs and fixed a little grammar

Comment: Thank you both for your comments so far. 
@Jean-Pierre Oosthuizen So my range needs to be dynamic. It starts at $C$7 and so far it goes to $C$137. every month there is new data added so the graphs should adjust automatically.

Comment: Are you using Office 2010 or 360 as I see you using `FullSeriesCollection`

Comment: It is the Office 360

Comment: The `.Parent`  section at the end is not working for me. What is your intention with it? Will have a look in the morning again

Comment: If it is not working for you, you can leave it out. It's just to set the exact size of the chart and where I want to place it and to define the name of the chart. Yes, that is very kind of you! I am still working on it if I achieve any progress I would write it in the comment section!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have rearranged a few lines of code and tried to place comments refering to them as well.

Let me know what works. Youjust might need to change `SeriesCollection` to `FullSeriesCollection`. Other than that the code works in my Excel 2010.

The first `Sub` I just get the `Range` size according to the data available in `Column` "C" from `Row` 7.

Let me know.

```
Option Explicit

Sub graphik_erstellen()

    'You always want to use direct reference to a sheet/range chart
    'Refering to the WorkBook they are in and the worksheet as well.
    'especially if you are opening multiple WorkBooks / Sheets
    Dim CurrentWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Set CurrentWorkSheet = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Dynamically finding the end of the data in Column C
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = CurrentWorkSheet.Cells(CurrentWorkSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    'Setting the range using the document reference aswell
    Dim AKB As Range
    Set AKB = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(7, "C"), Cells(LastRow, "C"))


    Call graphik(AKB)

End Sub

Sub graphik(Name As Range)

    Dim DataChart As Chart
    Dim RngToCover As Range
    Set DataChart = Workbooks("Book1").Charts.Add

    'With Excel 2010 the line above will automatically add the chart as a sheet and not aobject in a sheet
    'Set DataChart = DataChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Charts")


    With DataChart
        .Name = "Charts" ' This will be the Name of the CHart Tab
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SetSourceData Source:=Name

        'You can see below I avoided the Select and Selection
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            'Using Offset I just used the data one cell to the left of the range
            .XValues = Name.Offset(0, -1)
            .Name = "SERIES1"
            With .Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
        End With

        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "MIDDEL TOP TEXT" 'Name & ", Volumen (nach Korrektur)"
        .HasLegend = True
        With .Legend
            .Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
            .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 11
            .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        End With

        'Not sure about this, it doesnt work in my Excel 2010
        '
        With .Parent
            .Top = 100
            .Left = 100
            .Height = 287.149606299
            .Width = 543.685039370078
            .Name = Name & "_chart"
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Let me know what your intention is for the Sheet and Chart names and then I can help with getting that to what you need as well.

Comment: Dear Jean-Pierre. thank you very much for your professional response! I just shortly adjusted the sheet name and that's it, it works :) !
I really appreciate your help!! Hope you have a good week and thanks again

Comment: I am glad you got the assistance you needed. remember to upvote the answers you find useful as well.

Comment: my reputation is still to low so I can't upvote it. as soon as i can, i will.

Comment: ahhh yes, forgot about that. Enjoy